# what does (tr \\n \\0 <file.txt) mean?

Tags: bash, tr

context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13941223/15603477
I do understand `xargs chmod 755 <file.txt`

> For bigger amount of files, or almost any number of lines in your
> input file...
>
> For many binutils tools, like chown, chmod, rm, cp -t ...
>
> ```
> xargs chmod 755 <file.txt
> ```
>
> If you have special chars and/or a lot of lines in file.txt.
>
> ```
> xargs -0 chmod 755 < <(tr \\n \\0 <file.txt)
> ```

I not sure `(tr \\n \\0 <file.txt)` meaning?
In **man tr** the following is what I found:

```
\\     backslash        
\n     new line
```

Comment: Side note: by looking at the title I was like 'why would anyone want `\\o` in this context?' And then I realized it's [this thing](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5544/108618) again. Oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\\` represents a backslash, but there's two levels of escaping here.

First, the shell looks at the command line and processes quotes, here, `\\n` turns into `\n`. Equally, one could write `'\n'` or `"\n"`, they'd also produce `\n`.

Then, `tr` sees `\n` and takes it to mean the newline character. Similarly `\\0` turns to `\0`, which means the NUL byte, the one with numerical value zero.

The idea there is to convert the input from one that uses a newline to separate the pathnames, to one that uses the NUL byte to separate them. NUL is a natural separator since it's only character that's invalid in pathnames and also the `-0` option to `xargs` stops it from doing other special processing to the input: by default `xargs` processes quotes (in its own way, not exactly compatible with the shell's quoting rules), and treats any whitespace as a separator. It's probably better not to use plain `xargs`.

The `-0` option isn't standard, however, but is relatively widely supported. Also, with a conversion like that, you still can't represent filenames that contain *newlines*, but you can represent everything else, including spaces and quotes.

---

The `<(...)` thing is called process substitution, it provides the output of a command to read as if it was a file. It's a sort of a generalization of a pipe, and here, could be replaced with one.

I would write

```
xargs -0 chmod 755 < <(tr \\n \\0 <file.txt)
```

as

```
tr '\n' '\0' <file.txt | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

(again, `\\n` = `'\n'`)

Comment: `-0` (from GNU `xargs`)  is not standard but is more widely supported than `-d` or `-a` which you could use here as `xargs -d '\n' -a file.txt chmod 755 --`. Beside that `--`, you'd likely want to use `-r` (another GNU extension found in some other implementations, even enabled by default on some BSDs).

Comment: @ilkkachu can you help me with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/683588/505362)

Answer (score 1):

`tr \\n \\0` replaces `\n` (new line) with `\0` a NUL character so the content of the `file.txt` can be passed as null-terminated strings as input to `xargs -0`, which expected `\0` as the line separator. Without `-0` `xargs` expects its input to be separated by spaces and newlines which doesn't work if your `file.txt` contains spaces.

Comment: It's not only spaces and newlines. Other blank characters, single quotes, double quotes, backslashes, and with some implementations underscores or byte sequences that don't form valid characters would also be a problem.