# what does [ -z "${foo/[yn] and [-z expression] mean in bash?

Tags: bash

**Context**: while read -u, using dedicated fd  to run a command line for each line of a file.
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13941223/15603477

```
while read -u 7 filename;do
    ans=
    while [ -z "$ans" ]; do
        read -p "Process file '$filename' (y/n)? " -sn1 foo
        [ "$foo" ] && [ -z "${foo/[yn]}" ] && ans=$foo || echo '??'
    done
    if [ "$ans" = "y" ]; then
        echo Yes
        echo "Processing '$filename'."
    else
        echo No
    fi
done 7<file.txt
```

I don't understand the **do** block:

```
do
    read -p "Process file '$filename' (y/n)? " -sn1 foo
    [ "$foo" ] && [ -z "${foo/[yn]}" ] && ans=$foo || echo '??'
done
```

I googled *sn1*, seems no good result. **-z** is also not easy to search.
What I know;

> "&&" is used to chain commands together, such that the next command is
> run if and only if the preceding command exited without errors (or,
> more accurately, exits with a return code of 0).

> ${parameter/pattern/string} The pattern is expanded to produce a
> pattern just as in filename expansion. Parameter is expanded and the
> longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string.

but here **${foo/[yn]}** don't have replace string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading `man bash`

> `read`
>
> `-s`     Silent mode.  If input is coming from a terminal, characters are not echoed.
>
> `-n nchars`
> `read`  returns  after  reading  *nchars*  characters rather than waiting for a complete line of input, but honors a delimiter if
> fewer than nchars characters are read before the delimiter.

The code `read -p "Process file '$filename' (y/n)? " -sn1 foo` prints the prompt and reads a single char without echoing input.

> `-z string`
> True if the length of string is zero.

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
> ... If *string* is null, matches of *pattern* are deleted and the `/` following pattern may be omitted.

The code `[ "$foo" ]&& [ -z "${foo/[yn]}" ]&& ans=$foo || echo '??'`

checks if foo is either `y` or `n` otherwise prints '??'

Comment: I would really appreciate your effort to tell me why  `-z string` ==  True if the length of string is zero. Since `man read` there is no -z option.  And I already googled *-z mean in bash*

Comment: Open `man bash`, search for `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` section. I have already quoted `-z` description in my answer.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html Thanks.